# File are not getting rename in the same folder

Tags: perl

I am trying to rename the existing file name with Kernel.txt on the basis of "Linux kernel Version" or "USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED". Script is running without any error but no output is coming. The changed file needs to be in the same folder(F1,F2,F3) as it was earlier.

```
Top dir: Log
 SubDir: F1,F2,F3
    F1: .bin file,.txt file,.jpg file
    F2: .bin file,.txt file,.jpg file
    F3: .bin file,.txt file,.jpg file

#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use File::Basename;
use File::Spec;
use Cwd;
chdir('C:\\doc\\logs');
my $dir_01 = getcwd;

my $all_file=find ({ 'wanted' => \&renamefile }, $dir_01);
sub renamefile 
{
  if ( -f and /.txt?/ )
  {
   my @files = $_;
   foreach my $file (@files)
  {
    open (FILE,"<" ,$file) or die"Can not open the file";
    my @lines = <FILE>; 
    close FILE;
    for my $line ( @lines ) 
    {
       if($line=~ /Linux kernel Version/gi || $line=~ /USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED/gi)
       {    
         my $dirname = dirname($file); # file's directory, so we rename only the file itself.
         my $file_name = basename($file); # File name fore renaming.
         my $new_file_name = $file_name;
         $new_file_name =~ s/.* /Kernal.txt/g; # replace the name with Kernal.txt
         rename($file, File::Spec->catfile($dirname, $new_file_name)) or die $!; 
        }
     }
   }
  } 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code looks a bit like *cargo-cult programming*. That is, some constructs are here without indication that you are understanding what this is doing.

---

```
chdir('C:\\doc\\logs');
my $dir_01 = getcwd;
```

Do yourself a favour and use forward slashes, even for Windows pathnames. This is generally supported.

Your directory diagram says that there is a top dir `Log`, yet you chdir to `C:/doc/logs`. What is it?

You do realize that `$dir_01` is a very nondescriptive name, and is the path you just chdir'd to? Also, `File::Find` does not require you to start in the working directory. That is, the `chdir` is a bit useless here. You actually want:

```
my $start_directory = "C:/doc/Log"; # or whatever
```

---

```
my $all_file=find ({ 'wanted' => \&renamefile }, $dir_01);
```

I'm not sure what the return value of `find` would mean. But I'm sure that we don't have to put it into some unused variable.

When we provide key names with the `=>` fat comma, we don't have to manually quote these keys. Therefore:

```
find({ wanted => \&renamefile }, $start_directory);
```

---

```
/.txt?/
```

This regex does the following:

- match any character (that isn't a newline),
- followed by literal `tx`,
- and optionally a `t`. the `?` is a zero-or-one quantifier.

If you want to match filenames that end with `.txt`, you should do

```
/\.txt$/
```

the `\.` matches a literal period. The `$` anchors the regex at the end of the string.

---

```
my @files = $_;
foreach my $file (@files) {
  ...;
}
```

This would normally be written as

```
my $file = $_;
...;
```

You assign the value of `$_` to the `@files` array, which then has *one* element: The `$_` contents. Then you loop over this *one* element. Such loops don't deserve to be called loops.

---

```
open (FILE,"<" ,$file) or die"Can not open the file";
my @lines = <FILE>; 
close FILE;
for my $line ( @lines ) 
{ ... }
```

Ah, where to begin?

1. Use lexical variables for file handles. These have the nice property of closing themselves.
2. For error handling, `use autodie`. If you really want to do it yourself, the error message should contain two important pieces of information:

   - the name of the file you couldn't open (`$file`)
   - the reason why the open failed (`$!`)

   That would mean something like `... or die "Can't open $file: $!"`.
3. Don't read the whole file into an array and loop over *that*. Instead, be memory-efficient and *iterate* over the lines, using a `while(<>)`-like loop. This only reads one line at a time, which is much better.

Combined, this would look like

```
use autodie; # at the top

open my $fh, "<", $file;
LINE: while (<$fh>) {
  ...; # no $line variable, let's use $_ instead
}
```

Oh, and I labelled the loop (with `LINE`) for later reference.

---

```
if($line=~ /Linux kernel Version/gi || $line=~ /USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED/gi) { ... }
```

Putting the `/g` flag on regexes turns them into an iterator. you *really* don't want that. And I'm not quite sure if that case-insensitive matching is really neccessary. You can move the `||` or into the regex, with the regex alternation `|`. As we now use `$_` to contain the lines, we don't have to manually bind the regex to a string. Therefore, we can write:

```
if (/Linux Kernel Version|USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED/i) { ... }
```

---

```
my $dirname = dirname($file); # file's directory, so we rename only the file itself.
my $file_name = basename($file); # File name fore renaming.
```

The by default, the original `$_`, and therefore our `$file`, only contains the filename, but not the directory. This isn't a problem: File::Find `chdir`'d into the correct directory. This makes our processing a lot easier. If you want to have the directory, use the `$File::Find::dir` variable.

---

```
my $new_file_name = $file_name;
$new_file_name =~ s/.* /Kernal.txt/g;
```

The `/.* /` regex says:

- match anything up to including the last space
- If this matches, replace the matched part with `Kernal.txt`.

The `/g` flag is completely useless here. Are you sure you don't want `Kernel.txt` with an *e*? And why the space in the filename? I don't quite understand that. If you want to rename the file *to* `Kernel.txt`, just assign that as a string, instead of doing weird stuff with substitutions:

```
my $new_file_name = "Kernel.txt";
```

---

```
rename($file, File::Spec->catfile($dirname, $new_file_name)) or die $!;
```

We already established that an error message should also include the filename, or even better: we should use automatic error handling.

Also, we are already in the correct directory, so we don't have to concatenate the new name with the directory.

```
rename $file => $new_file_name; # error handling by autodie
last LINE;
```

That should be enough. Also note that I leave the *LINE* loop. Once we renamed the file, there is no need to check the other lines as well.

Comment: Thanks for you such a nice expatiation . It is going to give me great help in future. here i have one doubt without closing the $fh can we rename the file. actually I tried but got error.

Comment: @Maverick Yes, some OSes (like Windows, I think) do require the filehandle to be closed before renaming. But that isn't difficult, just stick an explicit `close $fh;` before the `rename`.

Comment: one last question .. the same thing if i want to do with more then one file i mean different files then can it possible.

Comment: `File::Find` doesn't stop after the first `rename`. Inside your `renamefile` you are free to test for other conditions as well.